# Getstylesheets in JavaFX isn't working and throwing Exception in Application start method

Tags: java, css, maven, javafx

My code was working fine, I was able to run my project and the gui was working. This is my first time using maven so it's possible that I messed up something with that. When I tried adding a css stylesheet it all broke down. This line in particular is what is causing the issue:
`scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());`
It's throwing the error "Exception in Application start method"

I tried using the absolute filepath and relative filepath of application.css but that didn't do anything.

This is my Main.java

```
package com.traptricker.etherminetrackerjavafx;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends javafx.application.Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        Image icon = new Image("file:src/main/extras/logo.png");
        stage.getIcons().add(icon);
        stage.setTitle("Ethermine Tracker");
        // Gets the css string and adds it to the scene
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

This is my application.css stylesheet:

```
.root {
    --fxbackground-color: "black";
}
```

This is my project structure:
[image]

This is my whole error

```
"D:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk11.0.11_9\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=58417:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\11.0.2\javafx-controls-11.0.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\11.0.2\javafx-graphics-11.0.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\11.0.2\javafx-fxml-11.0.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-web\11.0.2\javafx-web-11.0.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-media\11.0.2\javafx-media-11.0.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\11.0.1\javafx-base-11.0.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\4.1.1\selenium-java-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\google\auto\service\auto-service-annotations\1.0.1\auto-service-annotations-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\google\auto\service\auto-service\1.0.1\auto-service-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\google\auto\auto-common\1.2\auto-common-1.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-devtools-v85\4.1.1\selenium-devtools-v85-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-devtools-v94\4.1.1\selenium-devtools-v94-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-devtools-v95\4.1.1\selenium-devtools-v95-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-devtools-v96\4.1.1\selenium-devtools-v96-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edge-driver\4.1.1\selenium-edge-driver-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\4.1.1\selenium-firefox-driver-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-xpi-driver\4.1.1\selenium-firefox-xpi-driver-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\4.1.1\selenium-ie-driver-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-opera-driver\4.1.1\selenium-opera-driver-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec\4.1.70.Final\netty-codec-4.1.70.Final.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-handler\4.1.70.Final\netty-handler-4.1.70.Final.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-resolver\4.1.70.Final\netty-resolver-4.1.70.Final.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-exporter-logging\1.9.1\opentelemetry-exporter-logging-1.9.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-metrics\1.9.1-alpha\opentelemetry-sdk-metrics-1.9.1-alpha.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-logs\1.9.1-alpha\opentelemetry-sdk-logs-1.9.1-alpha.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-api-metrics\1.9.1-alpha\opentelemetry-api-metrics-1.9.1-alpha.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\asynchttpclient\async-http-client-netty-utils\2.12.3\async-http-client-netty-utils-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-socks\4.1.60.Final\netty-codec-socks-4.1.60.Final.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-handler-proxy\4.1.60.Final\netty-handler-proxy-4.1.60.Final.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-epoll\4.1.60.Final\netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.60.Final-linux-x86_64.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-kqueue\4.1.60.Final\netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.60.Final-osx-x86_64.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\reactivestreams\reactive-streams\1.0.3\reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\typesafe\netty\netty-reactive-streams\2.0.4\netty-reactive-streams-2.0.4.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\sun\activation\jakarta.activation\1.2.2\jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\4.1.1\selenium-safari-driver-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\4.1.1\selenium-support-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.32\slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.8.8\gson-2.8.8.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.14.2\jsoup-1.14.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\github\docker-java\docker-java\3.2.12\docker-java-3.2.12.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\github\docker-java\docker-java-core\3.2.12\docker-java-core-3.2.12.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\github\docker-java\docker-java-api\3.2.12\docker-java-api-3.2.12.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.10.3\jackson-annotations-2.10.3.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.6\commons-io-2.6.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.21\commons-compress-1.21.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.10.3\jackson-databind-2.10.3.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.10.3\jackson-core-2.10.3.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcpkix-jdk15on\1.64\bcpkix-jdk15on-1.64.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.64\bcprov-jdk15on-1.64.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.30\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.30.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\github\docker-java\docker-java-transport-httpclient5\3.2.12\docker-java-transport-httpclient5-3.2.12.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\github\docker-java\docker-java-transport\3.2.12\docker-java-transport-3.2.12.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\client5\httpclient5\5.0.3\httpclient5-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\core5\httpcore5\5.0.2\httpcore5-5.0.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.13\commons-codec-1.13.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\failureaccess\1.0.1\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\listenablefuture\9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava\listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.8.0\checker-qual-3.8.0.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.5.1\error_prone_annotations-2.5.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.3\j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\brotli\dec\0.1.2\dec-0.1.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.12.0\commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-text\1.9\commons-text-1.9.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.9.4\commons-beanutils-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.2\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-collections4\4.4\commons-collections4-4.4.jar -p "C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-classes-kqueue\4.1.70.Final\netty-transport-classes-kqueue-4.1.70.Final.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-media\11.0.2\javafx-media-11.0.2-win.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\ikonli\ikonli-javafx\12.2.0\ikonli-javafx-12.2.0.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-http\4.1.1\selenium-http-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\11.0.2\javafx-graphics-11.0.2-win.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\net\synedra\validatorfx\0.1.13\validatorfx-0.1.13.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk\1.9.1\opentelemetry-sdk-1.9.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\4.1.1\selenium-remote-driver-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\beust\jcommander\1.81\jcommander-1.81.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\11.0.2\javafx-fxml-11.0.2-win.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\11.0.1\javafx-base-11.0.1-win.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-web\11.0.2\javafx-web-11.0.2-win.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-classes-epoll\4.1.70.Final\netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.70.Final.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\ikonli\ikonli-core\12.2.0\ikonli-core-12.2.0.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna\5.8.0\jna-5.8.0.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-spi\1.9.1\opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-spi-1.9.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\net\jodah\failsafe\2.4.4\failsafe-2.4.4.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport-native-unix-common\4.1.70.Final\netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.70.Final.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-codec-http\4.1.70.Final\netty-codec-http-4.1.70.Final.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\controlsfx\controlsfx\11.1.0\controlsfx-11.1.0.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\4.1.1\selenium-chrome-driver-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure\1.9.1-alpha\opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-1.9.1-alpha.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-buffer\4.1.70.Final\netty-buffer-4.1.70.Final.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\11.0.2\javafx-controls-11.0.2-win.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chromium-driver\4.1.1\selenium-chromium-driver-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\github\bonigarcia\webdrivermanager\5.0.3\webdrivermanager-5.0.3.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-common\1.9.1\opentelemetry-sdk-common-1.9.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-common\4.1.70.Final\netty-common-4.1.70.Final.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.2\byte-buddy-1.12.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\dlsc\formsfx\formsfx-core\11.4.2\formsfx-core-11.4.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-sdk-trace\1.9.1\opentelemetry-sdk-trace-1.9.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-api\1.9.1\opentelemetry-api-1.9.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\bootstrapfx\bootstrapfx-core\0.4.0\bootstrapfx-core-0.4.0.jar;D:\Users\jackg\Desktop\Java Code\Ethermine Tracker JavaFX\target\classes;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-context\1.9.1\opentelemetry-context-1.9.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\30.1.1-jre\guava-30.1.1-jre.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\com\opencsv\opencsv\5.5.2\opencsv-5.5.2.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\4.1.1\selenium-api-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\asynchttpclient\async-http-client\2.12.3\async-http-client-2.12.3.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\eu\hansolo\tilesfx\11.48\tilesfx-11.48.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\opentelemetry\opentelemetry-semconv\1.9.1-alpha\opentelemetry-semconv-1.9.1-alpha.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\ous\jtoml\2.0.0\jtoml-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\io\netty\netty-transport\4.1.70.Final\netty-transport-4.1.70.Final.jar;C:\Users\jackg\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-json\4.1.1\selenium-json-4.1.1.jar" -m com.traptricker.etherminetrackerjavafx/com.traptricker.etherminetrackerjavafx.Main
Dec 30, 2021 2:53:08 AM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 17 by JavaFX runtime of version 11.0.1
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.traptricker.etherminetrackerjavafx/com.traptricker.etherminetrackerjavafx.Main.start(Main.java:26)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.traptricker.etherminetrackerjavafx.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Probably the CSS file isn’t getting deployed from `src/main/java`. It’s impossible to really know without seeing your build folder.

Comment: css is a resource, it belongs under the resources directory (next to view.fxml), not the java directory.